# Hyperbolic right-angled hexagon

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Is there any equation looks like **Cagnolli’s first formula**(for hyperbolic triangle ABC):
$$\sin\frac{S}{2}=\frac{\sinh\frac{a}{2}\sinh\frac{b}{2}\sin C}{\cosh\frac{c}{2}}$$
for hyperbolic right-angled hexagons?

Or any formula between its area($\pi$)and lengths?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 10):

The formula is:

$S = \pi,$ thanks to Gauss-Bonnet.

Answer (score 8):

As Igor points out $S=\pi$ for a right-angled hexagon. In general, the area of a hyperbolic right-angled $n$-gon will be $\frac{\pi}{2}(n-4)$ (here $n>4$ is required for hyperbolicity). More generally, knowing the angles (in fact just the angle sum) and the number of sides will determine the area of a hyperbolic polygon. The formula in the question is equivalent to determining the sum of the two other angles in the triangle.

However, it may be worth mentioning that Chapter 2 of [Thurston's notes](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/) has a treatment of hyperbolic right-angled polygons, which ends with a Law of Sines for right angled hexagons:

$$\frac{\sinh A}{\sinh \alpha}=\frac{\sinh B}{\sinh \beta}=\frac{\sinh C}{\sinh \gamma}$$

where $A,B,C, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are as in the figure below (taken from Thurston's notes Chapter 2, page 26). 
[image: Thurston's notes, Chapter 2, page 26]