# Best source for classification of right-angled hyperbolic hexagons

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

A standard fact that underlies the Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates on Teichmuller space is the fact that for all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive real numbers, there exists a unique hyperbolic hexagon whose angles are all right angles such that in their natural circular order the sides are $(a,x,b,y,c,z)$ for some positive real numbers $x,y,z$.

I know two sources that claim to prove this.  In Hubbard's book "Teichmuller theory, volume 1" he has a proof, but it rests on Exercise 3.5.5 (which he describes as "surprisingly tricky", and which I can only solve with a really terrible and unenlightening calculation).  In Farb-Margalit's "Primer on mapping class groups", there is also a proof, but they essentially assert something equivalent to that exercise without proof.

**Question**: Does anyone know a source with a complete proof?  Even better, a proof that minimizes terrible calculations.

Comment: "Ratcliffe, Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds is decent. (See the section on hyperbolic trigonometry.) "   quote from comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076278/the-notion-of-a-right-angled-hexagon-in-hyperbolic-geometry/1076290

Comment: @WillJagy: I had forgotten about that one.  Looking at it, it does give all the details, but via a gigantic wall of formulas (sadly, par for the course in that book).  Hopefully someone will know a more enlightening way of doing it...

Comment: Apparently Thurston gave a very simple "Law of Sines"   for right angled hexagons, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278365/hyperbolic-right-angled-hexagon  I will check, my guess is Thurston gave a proof that I would, well, like.

Comment: http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/2.pdf

Comment: Alright, Thurston concludes with a couple of diagrams after presenting the hyperbolic Laws of sines, and two cosines. Those  are in my little article http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

Comment: I think it can be found in Buser's (Birkhäuser) book "Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces".

Comment: I've requested Fenchel's book, Elementary geometry in hyperbolic space

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite proof is described well in this [blog post](https://theinnerframe.org/2020/03/10/pairs-of-pants/) (which attributes it to Hermann Karcher, though I first heard a version of it back in graduate school, so it should probably just be called folklore).  It is entirely synthetic and calculation-free.

Answer (score 2):

Section 7.19 (Hexagons) of Beardon's book *The geometry of discrete groups* gives a proof.

Comment: Sam,   does it show Thurston's claim   about right angled pentagons,  if $A,B$  are lengths of two consecutive sides, and $D$  the side that has no common vertex with either of those two, then $\cosh D  = \sinh A \sinh B \; ? \; $ This is 2.6.17 on the final page of http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/2.pdf , where 2.6.18 is his Law of Sin(h)es for right angled hexagons.  It ought to come from clever drawings  and a little trig, I don't see it.

Comment: Dear Will - Yes.  It is in Section 7.18 (Pentagons).

Comment: Thank you. I have books about non-Euclidean plane geometry owing to contact with Hartshorne  and Greenberg. Neither book appears to do any pentagons and hexagons, but both Lambert and Saccheri quadrilaterals. Oh, I found Beardon and printed out 7.17-7.19

Answer (score 0):

A proof of this that I enjoyed reading appears as lemma 3.6 in *Thurston's Work on Surfaces,* by Fathi, Laudenbach, and Poénaru.